# Selecting a row in a NSTableView (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I want my Mac App to do something when a row in my table view is selected. In iOS, I could use `didSelectRowAt` to do something when a table view cell was tapped:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Some code
}
```

In iOS, when a table view cell was tapped, `didSelectRowAt` would be executed. How do you do something like this with NSTableView in macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Implement [`tableViewSelectionDidChange(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1528567-tableviewselectiondidchange) of `NSTableViewDelegate` and check [`selectedRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1535010-selectedrow) or [`selectedRowIndexes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1533844-selectedrowindexes)
2. Use Cocoa Bindings: Bind `selectionIndexes` of the table view to a `dynamic` var of type `IndexSet` and use the `didSet` observer.

Comment: 3. Observe `NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification`. and check `selectedRow` or `selectedRowIndexes`.

Comment: @Willeke Technically that's the same as 1. and you have to add the observer.

Comment: The observer doesn't have to be the delegate.